# "on the one hand" without the other hand

Tags: idioms

I've been wondering if it would look strange if I didn't include both "pairs" of this idiom, e.g.:

> In recent times a significant increase of popularity of teaching
>   English as a foreign language in kindergartens is observed. However,
>   it may be surrounded by many doubts, the main reasons being the great
>   demand for this type of activities from parents, and at the same time
>   the lack of specific, clear guidelines governing the teaching of
>   English, which could be of help to those responsible for introduction
>   of such classes into kindergartens.

I know it's possible (and indeed used) the other way around but I am not sure in this case.

Comment: Sorry @JStrange, I was going to try a rewrite of your sentence but I am not clear on its meaning either.  I seem to see a place for "on the other hand", where you say "at the same time" - but did not feel confident enough in my understanding of your intent to do the rewrite.

Comment: @KristinaLopez +1 I think you understood the intention correctly. "At the same time" should be replaced with "on the other hand". But the sentence following the idiom (or the whole passage) needs work.

Comment: The Brony (My Little Pony) fandom goes in the opposite direction with that, with a fondness for quadruple comparisons. *"...And on the fourth hoof..."*

Comment: Edited for context.

Comment: @jstrange: should be "this type of *activity*" or "*these types* of activities"

Comment: From the back cover of "The Definitive Biography of PDQ Bach" by Peter Schickele: "On the one hand, Peter Schickele is very funny. On the other hand, he wears a ring."

Comment: Ehm, is it me or does your sentence now not have "on the one hand" at all?

Comment: Here's a rewrite of your paragraph: _Teaching English as a foreign language in kindergarten has recently become trendy, but it may not be a sound idea. Despite the great demand from parents who want their children to learn English as early as possible, there are no surefire methods for teaching English to kindergartners._ There's no need for "on the one/other hand" in the paragraph.

Comment: I'm voting to close as Not A Real Question. The title of the question no longer relates to the current question text, and I don't see anything here serving any purpose.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. The idiom being asked about no longer even appears in the example.

Answer (score 4):

There’s no point at all in writing *on the one hand* if you aren’t going to balance it with *on the other hand*. You might just as well leave it out. Quite apart from that, the sentence is not at all clear. In fact, it’s not even a sentence as commonly understood, because it lacks a finite verb in the main clause.

Comment: Serves me right for not including the whole context! It's added now.